# Conditionally formatting cells in Google Sheets (old) to change colour on/after a certain date

Tags: date, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

First post on Stack Overflow, I've checked around for similar problems on the forum but I haven't found quite what I'm looking for. Apologies if I'm covering old ground.

I have a spreadsheet in which I would like to first change the background colour of some cells, then use conditional formatting according to a custom formula to have the colour change to something else on a particular date, and remain that colour indefinitely or until the formatting is removed. Using the 'date is before/after/etc.'

The formula I am using is:

```
=today()>=26/01/2015
```

Say I change the background colour of my cells from yellow to grey and then apply this rule, instructing Sheets to turn the cells' background yellow again on the date I specify. The date at the time of writing is before the date in the above formula so I should not see any colour change, right? Yet the formatting is applied anyway.

`=today()` returns today's date `(21st Jan at the time of writing)`
, and 42,025.00 when formatted as a number.

`26/01/2015` is `42030.00` when formatted as a number.

And still the expression: `=today()<=26/01/2015 returns 'FALSE'.`

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just realised I've got a typo in my question. Meant to say "Using the 'date is before/after/etc.' drop-downs isn't and option." and I don't think they would make sense in this context anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is trying to enter a formula where a formula is not valid. What is being taken/acted upon is what Google understands from the formula, which is `=today()`, the rest is ignored.